# I am using flexbox to create my layout, however, I can't properly position the elements on my last row. Can I recreate the same layout with grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I have a flex container with a width that is not fixed and a bunch of children inside of it with fixed width. I've set `flex-wrap` to `wrap` and `justify-content` to `space-evenly`. This works fine and dandy for most parts, however, the position of the elements on the last row are not where I want them to be

I understand that the element on the last row are where they are because of justify-content: space-evenly. I am wondering if it is possible to space the content evenly when the row is full whilst keeping the children on the last line to the left side of the div. It should look something like this:

[image]

Sadly, I read that targeting elements on the last row is not actually possible with flexbox right now and that I should look into other alternatives. This is why I am wondering if its possible to recreate the same layout with grid whilst fixing the last row issues I'm having

```css
    .cards-list {
        padding-top: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .card {
        width: 120px;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: red;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class='cards-list'>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
   <div class='card'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need a fallback for IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this when using flex for grid layout when I need a fallback for `display: grid;`. You can add empty grid fillers with the same width/margin as the regular cards, and set the height to 0. The formula is to have 1 less filler then your card row count, so 4 cards > 3 fillers, 8 cards > 7 fillers. Hope it's clear.

If you don't need a fallback you can use the class `.grid` in my example below.

**EDIT**
As you work with Vue you could do this. Remember that min-width is just a value I took it would have to change it to represent your breakpoints. If you like you don't even need that part. This is just a starter kit for you, it can be modified to your liking and project needs.

```
<template v-if="window.matchMedia('(min-width: 998px)').matches">
  <div v-for="i of 15" :key="`card-filler-grid-name-${i}`" class="card--filler" />
</template>
```

```css
.cards-list {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  max-width: 40rem;
}

.card {
  width: 120px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card--filler {
  width: 120px;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='cards-list'>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card--filler'></div>
  <div class='card--filler'></div>
  <div class='card--filler'></div>
  <div class='card--filler'></div>
</div>

<div class='grid'>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
  <div class='card'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and comment on why. Solid solution though, else just accept that it looks strange or move to grid. Still need a fallback solution for grid... I'll leave it here in case somebody needs it.

Comment: Oh my bad, I've seen the filler elements solution, however, I should've mentioned that the children elements are dynamically rendered using JavaScript based on an array of elements so I can't use that solution. I don't need an IE fallback.

Comment: @Bobimaru why would that be a problem? Are you using React/Vue/other framework/jQuery? As long as you know the amount you want maximum on each row you can use this.

Comment: I'm using Vue.js. I originally display around 300 cards, however, I can apply filters that change the number of displayed cards. So sometimes I only render 2 cards and sometimes I render up to 300. So I can never know if the row is gonna be filled or not.

Comment: @Bobimaru I mean what is the max amount per row? The total amount does not matter with this. If your row amount is to show 4, you add 3 fillers.

Comment: Well the thing is, there's no maximum per row, It depends on the size of the viewport. If the viewport is scaled down horizontally to 500px, I'll have 3 images and if it's 1920px, I'll have 16 images on the same row.

Comment: @Bobimaru well there you have it, it's a maximum of 16 :). The thing is that you only count the maxium in your largest viewport, it really does not matter for smaller. My point is you probably have a max width of the page and there for know the maxium amount that could possibly fit? If you like you could even make the assumption that a smaller size screen is mobile and there for will support grid and hide the fillers, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to set the size of space between each card, and the card will become flexible. Let's do this :

```css
.wrapper{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item{
  width: calc(25% - 40px); /* 25% for 4 items, 33% for 3, 50% for 2 .... -> substract the right and left margin*/
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

This solution is quite simple but very efficient. Hope it help you ! Codepen to edit code : https://codepen.io/ZellRDesign/pen/YzXNdLr

NB : for the mobile size : remember to add mediaqueries with justify-content: center; when there is only one column of card